# I am unable to use array elements in src attribute of img tag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I aim to render multiple images whose path I have already defined in an array called images. But when I **want to use it in the src attribute of an img tag**, for some reason it does not renders the image, even though the path is correct.

The code that I wrote in the react component was as follows:

```
let images=["../../../assets/temp.jpg", "../../../assets/temp2.jpg", "../../../assets/temp3.jpg"];
let n = images.length;
let imgArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    imgArray.push(<img src={images[i]} alt="image cover" />);
}
return(
    <div>
        {imgArray}
    </div>
);
```

The above code does not render the image provided as a path in src. But if I import the path and then provide that imported element as the src, then it works fine.

The tech I have used in my project is React.js and Bootstrap

Comment: In the resulting DOM in the browser, what is the value for `src`?  When the browser makes a request for that resource (in the network tab of the debugging tools), what is the server's response?  Is the path not correct?  Note that you're not *importing* anything here.  All this is doing is setting a literal string value as the `src` for an `<img>`.

Comment: You've already answered your own question. When your React code is compiled the path changes from (at a guess) `src` to `public`. So the path will be wrong. But when you import your images into the app they will be compiled properly with the rest of the code.

Comment: @Andy Thanks a lot, I get it now. I forgot that after the compilation, code is rendered in public and hence the path would change accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React uses JSX which cannot display arrays. In your code `{imgArray}` is an array of images, which you now need to loop through and convert to a JSX component/element.

The best approach is to use the `array.map` function built in to JS arrays. ​

```js
// use "const" not let if the var doesn't change
const imgArray = [
    {
        key: 'uniqueid1',
        src: 'path/to/img.png',
    },
];

return
   ​<div>
       ​{
            imgArray.map(_img => <img 
                src={_img.src} 
                key={_img.key}
                alt="image cover" 
            />)
        }
  ​</div>
);
```

You'll note we now don't need the for loop either.

> PS: Don't forget the "key" it's very important for React to reconcile the image elements you have created (and don't use the array index either)

More info:

- [List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)